# Render rdlc reports to PDF not working on azure websites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, report, rdlc, azure-web-app-service

I am having the following issue with my rdlc reports. I am creating an asp.net MVC application and need to use reports. All my reports work fine on my local machine, but on azure website I get the always this error:

```
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
```

On my azure bin folder I have the following dll's

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
```

and have a folder Reports with all my reports in it.

I also have change my reports properties Build Action to content and still nothing. Does any one know how can I resolve this issue.

The code that I am using and works fine on my localhost

```
        LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "Model1.rdlc");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            lr.ReportPath = path;
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }

        ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("Model1");
        lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
        string reportType = id;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        string deviceInfo =

        "<DeviceInfo>" +
        "  <OutputFormat>" + id + "</OutputFormat>" +
        "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
        "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
        "  <MarginTop>0.2in</MarginTop>" +
        "  <MarginLeft>0.1in</MarginLeft>" +
        "  <MarginRight>0.1in</MarginRight>" +
        "  <MarginBottom>0.3in</MarginBottom>" +
         " <orientation>Landscape</orientation>" +

        "</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;

        renderedBytes = lr.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);

        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
```

Comment: If my answer below helped, don't hesitate to validate it :-)

Answer (score 3):

Azure App Service Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox to isolate apps.
This sandbox is blocking various APIs calls, like GDI+ APIs.
The problem might come from this limitation.
Please see the following documentation page for more détails: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox